# When I type the wrong password the Display is flickering

Tags: iphone, xcode

While logging, when I enter a wrong password the screen starts to flicker. Here is the code:

```
-(void)ValidateUser
{
    if(userObj)
    {
        if([userObj.userPassword isEqualToString:_txtPassword.text])
        {
            PlistUtility *objPlist = [[PlistUtility alloc] init];
            NSDictionary *loginDict = [objPlist ReadPlist:@"LoginCheck"];
            NSString *isFirstTime = [loginDict objectForKey:@"isFirstTime"];
            NSMutableDictionary *updateLoginDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [updateLoginDict setValue:userObj.userId forKey:@"userId"];
            [updateLoginDict setValue:userObj.userName forKey:@"username"];
            sendLabelname = userObj.userName;


        NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:sendLabelname forKey:@"usernameLabel"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];         



        [updateLoginDict setObject:_txtCompanyID.text forKey:@"companyId"];
        [updateLoginDict setObject:_txtCompanyName.text forKey:@"companyName"];

        [objPlist WritetoPlist:@"LoginCheck" withData:updateLoginDict];

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.creativethoughts.co.in/wifier/GetAllSavedWifi.php?userid=%@",userObj.userId];
        NSString *result = [Server ConnectToServer:urlString :nil :@"GET"];
        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [result JSONValue];
        NSMutableDictionary *wifiDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        for(int i=0;i<[resultArray count];i++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *currentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc]init];
            currentDict = [resultArray objectAtIndex:i];
            MapWifi *objMappedWifi = [[MapWifi alloc]init];
            objMappedWifi.macAddress = [currentDict objectForKey:@"wifier_wifi_address"];
            objMappedWifi.wifiName = [currentDict objectForKey:@"wifier_wifi_name"];
            objMappedWifi.securityKey = [currentDict objectForKey:@"wifier_secret_pass"];
            [wifiDict setObject:objMappedWifi forKey:[currentDict objectForKey:@"wifier_wifi_address"]];
        }
        NSData *dataWifi = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:wifiDict];
        [objPlist WriteDatatoPlist:@"AddedWifi" withData:dataWifi];
        if([isFirstTime isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"terms" sender:self];
            });
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"home" sender:self];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(wrongPassword) withObject:nil];

      //  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertMessage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
else
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Please select a valid user" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    });


}
 [_loader stopAnimating];
```

}

```
-(void)wrongPassword
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Please enter a valid password." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

@try this code

```
-(void)wrongPassword
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Please enter a valid password." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was with the UI element picker view. It was running on background thread whenever password gets wrong.i used this code to run that in main thread and the problem got fixed

```
**dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self LoadActionSheet];
    });**
```